# How to seal message in javascript to communicate with PHP openssl_open in AES256

Tags: javascript, php, openssl, aes

I have a PHP application which can communicate with other PHP applications.
Theses apps exchange encrypted data.
A central app knows all public keys of other apps.
And other apps only know the public key of the central app.
The data are encrypted thanks to the openssl_seal PHP method.
And there are decrypted thanks to the openssl_open PHP method.
I use the "AES256" cypher method and generate an "iv" element.
In PHP no problem at all, everything is for the best in the best of all possible worlds …

But, now, I would like to do the same with an Ionic app (based on cordova and Angular 5).

I tried to use JSEncrypt and CryptoJS, but PHP dos not explain how openssl_seal works and I have some trouble to export my PHP code into Javascript one …

```php
function encrypt($message)
{
    $envKeys = [];
    $encMessage = '';
    $pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
";
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES256'));
    if (openssl_seal($message, $encMessage, $envKeys, [$pubKey], 'AES256', $iv) === false) {
        throw new Exception("Erreur lors du cryptage du message !");
    }
    return [base64_encode($encMessage), base64_encode($envKeys[0]), base64_encode($iv)];
}
```

```php
function decrypt($messageCrypte, $key, $iv)
{
    $privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    ";
    $message = '';
    openssl_open(base64_decode($messageCrypte), $message, base64_decode($key), $privateKey, 'AES256', base64_decode($iv));
    return $message;
}
```

```php
$crypted = encrypt('Test');
$embed = "<script>var encrypted = '$crypted[0]'; var envelope = '$crypted[1]'; var iv = '$crypted[2]'; </script>";
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsencrypt.js"></script>
    <?php echo $embed; ?>
    <script>
        var private_key = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
        `;

        var crypt = new JSEncrypt();
        crypt.setPrivateKey(private_key);
        var theKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(crypt.decrypt(envelope));
        console.log('The key', theKey);
        console.log('ciphertext', CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted));
        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            {ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted)},
            theKey,
            {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv)}
        );
        console.log('Decrypted', decrypted.toString());
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't have the original message "Test" … Only empty string …
I would like to be able to make an openssl_seal (like the PHP one) method in JS and an openssl_open (like the PHP one) using CryptoJS and JSEncrypt.
I think it's possible, maybe someone already did that …

### Edit

If someone is interested by this problem, I maybe found a lead : http://geekswithblogs.net/Strenium/archive/2013/01/27/converting-phprsquos-ldquoopenssl_sealrdquo-and-ldquoopenssl_openrdquo-into-.net.aspx
It is for .NET but it's a start …

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just do all the communication over an encrypted protocol (HTTPS, SSH, etc)?  That way most of the grunt-work is already done for you

Comment: We have to allow communication betwen a central app and other satelites apps.
The communication will be make over HTTPS but in this protocol the server can't validate the sender. Any apps with the url can send data. And I have to accept only data sent by known apps…
So which method can validate the sender with enough security ? Asymetric crypto … So we have decided to use openssl …
Secondly, I don't wan't to know if my problem is a good one ^^ I want to resolve it ;)